# Поток bmp преобразовывать в video c++

Tags: gif, bmp, imagemagick, ffmpeg, c++

Есть поток bmp, которые поступают с камеры. Я хочу эти bmp преобразовывать в какой-нибудь видеоформат.
Какой кодек лучше всего подключить? Смотрел на **magick++** и **ffmpeg**, на первый взгляд, не понравились. Может, что-то пропустил или уже все написано, а я придумываю велосипед?
Язык *C++*.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `ffmpeg`. Он умеет сам брать картинки с камеры и конвертировать в видео. `ImageMagick`, насколько мне известно, сам использует `ffmpeg`.